# Cant import SVG image in react component with rollup

Tags: reactjs, rollup

not sure what im missing here i added rollup-image-puling and rollup-svg-plugin but still fails to import image

```
import peerDepsExternal from "rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external";
import resolve from "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve";
import commonjs from "@rollup/plugin-commonjs";
import typescript from "rollup-plugin-typescript2";
import postcss from "rollup-plugin-postcss";
import image from "@rollup/plugin-image";
import svg from 'rollup-plugin-svg'

const packageJson = require("./package.json");

export default {
  input: "src/index.ts",
  output: [
    {
      file: packageJson.main,
      format: "cjs",
      sourcemap: true
    },
    {
      file: packageJson.module,
      format: "esm",
      sourcemap: true
    }
  ],
  plugins: [
    peerDepsExternal(),
    resolve(),
    commonjs({
      namedExports: {
        'react-is': Object.keys(require('react-is')),
      },
    }),
    typescript({ useTsconfigDeclarationDir: true }),
    image(),
    svg(),
    postcss()
  ]
};
```

when i try to import a svg image into my component i get "cannot find module"